# Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.machineTypes.get' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

i am trying to create kubernetes cluster in GCP but i am unable to create and getting following error "Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.machineTypes.get' permission for 'projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/e2-medium'".
And also getting zonal error as follows
"Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/us-central1-a'".

Comment: what is the out put of this command - 'gcloud auth list' and also roles assigned to this service account?

Comment: 'gcloud auth list' this command gives me my account mail id

Comment: It seems, you don't have enough privileges to create kubernetes cluster. Please ask your organistation to grant you kubernetes admin privileges to spin up new cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have added a role "kubernetes Engine admin " to my account and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

From the error I understand that it is permission issue.

In order to create a kubernetes cluster [create a service](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) account and assigned the editor role the it. Now, [activate the service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) in gcloud shell. Using the following command [create a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create):

```
gcloud container clusters create sample-cluster
```

If still problem persist, you need to grant the following permission to the service account.

```
roles/compute.instanceAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

Comment: Using service account key file must be the latest idea, and it's always a bad idea. Same solution works by granting the role on the user account and not on the service account!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a permission issue. I have added "Kubernetes engine Admin" role to my user in IAM then i came to solve my issue to create a kubernetes cluster in GCP, Thanks for your suggestion.